# Strange undefined reference !!! undefined reference to `std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'

Tags: c++

When I am compiling my program

I am getting this error

```
undefined reference to `std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'
```

It feels that it is not albe to find reference in the standard libraries or something.
Is it some kind of lib conflict.
Basically I am trying to port piece of code which was on GCC 3.1.1 to 4.1.2

As there is compiler change I am facing this issue

Comment: I haven't used GCC enough to provide an answer, but you might want to provide the source code at least of line the compiler complains about.

Comment: @Pontus I doubt the error in his source, more likely his build setup or environment.

Comment: @CashCow: probably. What part is wrong might be easier to diagnose with source.

Comment: @CashCow: Without seeing the source that is imposable to tell. I would guess the problem is in the source and caused by incorrect types being used together.

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking with other components still on 3.1.1 or even linking with the wrong GNU library?

Comment: I have just copid the code in the different linux system which is redhat 5.3, and GNU 4.1.2.
Linking to 3.x.x is not a question as I m on whole new system.

Comment: try g++ --version. Note you must compile and link with g++ not gcc

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include` all the appropriate headers for the standard library components you're using?

For example,

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me like you are using some c++ code.
'std' namespace and the 'template'.

Try using g++ to compile your code and if that doesn´t work try to put "using namespace std;" after your include lines.

Can you please provide atleast some few lines from where the error is from?

Btw found this link with the same question asked: [Here](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-devel/2009/001087.html)

Where they suggest installing libstdc++.